# Paint not showing up on model

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I can't get the paint to show up on my model.  It's stuck with a black and white checkerboard on it.

[image]

I'm trying to paint on it but the paint barely shows up or it doesn't show up at all, I'm not sure because it's really hard to see.  I think I may have pressed a key on the keyboard that I shouldn't have.  I've only been using blender for a few weeks.

Comment: Use this link to upload the .blend file: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Is hard to guess what you've done so far. Please edit your question and add more information. If you can, also add images that show the current state of  your project and settings. To upload the file please read: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/help/

Comment: I bet you didn't save the image!

Comment: Please add some more details as to what you are doing and what is happening that you don't want.  Just a couple short sentences and a .blend file is not very clear and likely to get put on hold.